# Getting empty RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

It is my first time im working with RecyclerView and i have a problem. Im trying to get the View i a DrawerFragment. The Drawer menu is working fine but i cant see the RecyclerView there. Can anyone help me?

This is the Layout of my Fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DADADA"
tools:context="com.example.entwicklung1.designtestapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="#0064a7"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/zanderlogo" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here the code:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWNER = "user_learned_drawer";
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private MyAdapter adapter;

private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private View containerView;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public  List<Information> getData(){
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icons={R.drawable.ic_number1,R.drawable.ic_number2,R.drawable.ic_number3,R.drawable.ic_number4,R.drawable.ic_number5};
    String[] titles ={"News", "Produkte","Homepage","Kontakt","Anfahrt"};

    for(int i=0;i<titles.length; i++){
        Information current=new Information();
        current.iconId=icons[i];
        current.title=titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWNER, "false"));
    mFromSavedInstanceState = savedInstanceState != null ? true : false;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return layout;
}




public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView=getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(),
            drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if(!mUserLearnedDrawer){
                mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
                saveToPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWNER,mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
            }
            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            if(!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState){
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
}
}
```

And here the RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();

public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Information> data) {
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Information current = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        icon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
    }
}
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set data in the adapter constructor. So, your data is empty.

```
    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();

    public MyAdapter(Context context,List<Information> data) {
       inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
       this.data = data;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this statement
    }
```

**Update:**

Need to change orientation of the top LinearLayout to "vertical"

Comment: Thank you. But it doesnt solve the problem. Still blank Fragment.

Comment: try to set layout_height of the recyclview to match_parent. Just for test.

Comment: You set orientation of the the top LinearLayout to horizontal and first item width to match parent, so, your recycler view is out of the layout. You should set the orientation of the top LinearLayout to vertical

Comment: I updated my answer. Please accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that:

- List passed to the adapter must not be empty
- If empty, remember to call #notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter
- Setting a LayoutManager to the RecyclerView is mandatory